# searching in solr for specific values with dismax

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm using the dismax handler to perform solr search over records (boosting some fields).

In my index, I have a RetailerId for each document, as well as other fields.

My query needs to search for documents that have this RetailerId as well as keywords:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?qt=dismax&q=RetailerId:(27 OR 92) AND socks
```

What is the syntax for such a query?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) does not support boolean operators. For a query like the one you described, you need to use the Standard Query Handler.

**UPDATE**

I have made a couple of tests and the [fq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) parameter seems to work with dismax:
`/select?qt=dismax&q=socks&fq=RetailerId:(27 OR 92)`

Comment: That may be a problem. Is there any way to make this happen with Dismax? Can I add another param that filters on these, for example facets etc?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter by facet, user eDismax (extended disMax) that way you can say for instance `q= your query AND face_name:"facet value"`